# Relacionamentos na VIewModel com EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde um usuário terá vários dados. Para não estender muito a classe pensei em separar por categorias. Exemplo das classes:

- Usuario
- DadosPessoais
- DadosFamiliares
- Etc.

Para fazer isso no site pensei em criar tipo um carousel com boostrap e criar uma  `ViewModel` para armazenar todos os dados do candidato:

ex:

```
public class DadosCandidatoViewModel
{
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }

    public CandidatoViewModel CandidatoViewModel { get; set; }
    public DadosPessoaisViewModel DadosPessoaisViewModel { get; set; }
    //ETC

}
```

Ai já começa a dúvida, porque nem sei se é necessário, já que o *Model* de Candidato já tem os virtuais para essas tabelas, assim como essas outras tabelas também já tem candidato já que o relacionamento é de 1 pra 1 ou 0.

```
public class Candidato
{
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual DadosPessoais DadosPessoais { get; set; }
    public virtual DadosFamiliares DadosFamiliares { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cargo> Cargos { get; set; }

}

public class DadosPessoais
{
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }

    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public virtual Candidato Candidato { get; set; }
}
```

Minhas View Model Ficaram Assim:

```
public class CandidatoViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencher o campo Nome")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencher o campo CPF")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {1} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {1} caracteres")]
    //Criar Datatype de CPF
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public virtual DadosPessoaisViewModel DadosPessoais { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}


public class DadosPessoaisViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencher o campo Endereço")]
    [MaxLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {0} caracteres")]
    public string Sexo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencher o campo Endereço")]
    [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {0} caracteres")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Bom, primeiro preciso saber se estou fazendo certo, ou pelo menos indo pelo caminho certo, porque do jeito que está estou enfrentando vários problemas na hora de persistir os dados.

Abaixo tem a `View` que criei para o controle `DadosCandidatoViewModel` onde pretendo chamar as *Partial Views* para os Dados do Candidato:

```
@model Gestao_RH.MVC.ViewModels.DadosCandidatoViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DadosCandidato";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<!-- Div na qual o "carousel" será aplicado. -->
<div id="div-carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!-- Divs com efeito de transição. -->
        <div class="item active">

            @Html.Partial("~/Views/DadosPessoais/Edit.cshtml", Model)
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            Conteúdo da DIV 2.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Botões de navegação -->
    <div id="div-1" class="span2">
        <a id="a-1" class="btn" href="#div-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>Voltar para DIV 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="span2">
        <a id="a-2" class="btn" href="#div-carousel" data-slide="next">Avançar para DIV 2<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Aplica o efeito de "carousel" nas divs que possuirem a classe carousel.
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: false
            });

            // Oculta o botão de navegação para a div 1.
            $('#div-1').hide();

            // Aplica a transição quando houver click no link AVANÇAR.
            $("#a-1").click(function () {
                $('#div-carousel').carousel(0);
                $('#div-1').hide();
                $('#div-2').show();
                return false;
            });

            // Aplica a transição quando houver click no link VOLTAR.
            $("#a-2").click(function () {
                $('#div-carousel').carousel(1);
                $('#div-1').show();
                $('#div-2').hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Abaixo só um exemplo da *ViewModel* que Salva ou edita os Dados pessoais:

```
@model Gestao_RH.MVC.ViewModels.DadosCandidatoViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDadosPessoais", "DadosCandidato", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CandidatoViewModel.Nome);
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CandidatoId);

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DadosPessoaisViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CandidatoId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Sexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Sexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Sexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Endereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DadosPessoaisViewModel.Endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar " class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Isso aqui também também não esta dando certo:

```
public class DadosCandidatoController : Controller
{
    //  private readonly ProdutoRepository _ProdutoRepository = new ProdutoRepository();
    private readonly ICandidatoAppService _candidatoApp;
    private readonly IDadosPessoaisAppService _dadosPessoasApp;
    // GET: Produtos

    public DadosCandidatoController(ICandidatoAppService candidatoApp, IDadosPessoaisAppService dadosPessoaisApp)
    {
        _candidatoApp = candidatoApp;
        _dadosPessoasApp = dadosPessoaisApp;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DadosCandidato(int id)
    {
        var candidato = _candidatoApp.GetById(id);
        var DadosCandidatoViewModel = Mapper.Map<Candidato, DadosCandidatoViewModel>(candidato);


        return View("DadosCandidato", DadosCandidatoViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveDadosPessoais(DadosCandidatoViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var DadosPessoaisDomain = Mapper.Map<DadosPessoaisViewModel, DadosPessoais>(model.DadosPessoaisViewModel);


            if (_dadosPessoasApp.GetById(model.CandidatoId) == null)
            {

                _dadosPessoasApp.Add(DadosPessoaisDomain);
            }
            else
            {
                _dadosPessoasApp.Update(DadosPessoaisDomain);
            }


            return View("DadosCandidato", model);
        }


        return View("DadosCandidato", model);
    }
}
```

Qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda, minha cabeça está dando nó com o MVC.

Comment: Na sua controller, o que não está dando certo?

Answer (score 2):

Se a ideia é separar por *ViewModels* para que cada *ViewModel* seja representada por uma *Partial*, o raciocínio está errado.

A ideia de separar *Models* (ou *ViewModels*) é para o princípio de cardinalidade: normalmente a separação serve para determinadas associações ou agregações. No seu caso, não há necessidade desta separação.

Se os *Models* são iguais aos *ViewModels*, usar *ViewModels* na sua aplicação me parece algo sem muito sentido.

Você pode muito bem definir todo o seu *Model* desta forma:

```
public class Candidato
{
    [Key]
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    public virtual DadosPessoais DadosPessoais { get; set; }
    public virtual DadosFamiliares DadosFamiliares { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cargo> Cargos { get; set; }
}
```

Aparentemente você está usando [Automapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639618/CRUD-Opearations-using-AutoMapper-in-an-MVC-Applic) para mapear suas *ViewModels* em *Models*. Não sei o que faz sua camada de *App Service*, mas uma dica é usar o debug pra ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Morrison os dados do candidato serão uns 100 e talvez no futuro mude. o que vc me sugere é criar uma classe candidato e jogar tudo lá dentro? Não entendi...pelo que vi na sua sugestão vc pegou os dadosPessoais do candidato que são sexo e endereço, por exemplo, e jogo tudo na Model de Candidato. Na verdade a idéia é que esses dados pertencam a classe DadosPessoais e a mesma tenha um relacionamento de 1 pra 1 ou 0 com Candidato!

Comment: @PauloJardim Então os candidatos não necessariamente terão dados pessoais? Sim, minha sugestão é deixar tudo num *Model* só quando a cardinalidade é 0 ou 1 para fins de simplificação da regra de negócio em aplicação.

Comment: Exato, imagine que o processo de cadastro será por etapas, imagino que será muito desgastante dar um erro no meio do item 99 e ele ter de refazer tudo.

Answer (score -1):

Está indo certinho sim, Paulo. E é muito bacana ver esse nivel de organização e separação de responsabilidades, parabéns.

Trabalhar com `ViewModels` é essencial. O que falta na sua implementação é entender que vc pode trabalhar com conceito de `PageObject` - o mesmo conceito derivado do framework de testes Selenium - e fazer `PageViews`, onde essas *views* irão representar todo o modelo de sua página, ficando assim:

```
// Modelo de representação da sua view DadosCandidato
public class DadosCandidatoPageViewModel
{
    public int CandidatoId { get; set; }

    public CandidatoViewModel Candidato { get; set; }
    public DadosPessoaisViewModel DadosPessoais { get; set; }
    // ...    
}
```

E em sua *view*:

```
@model Gestao_RH.MVC.ViewModels.DadosCandidatoPageViewModel;
```

Assim fica definido quais dados serão passados para sua *view*.

Sobre a dúvida de enviar/criar `ViewModels` semalhantes às suas entidades: Não é um problema. Lembre-se que suas entidades/modelos devem ser isoladas de seus ambientes. Assim, também, evita-se de "sujar" suas entidades com notações como `Required`, `MinLength`, etc. Que são notações específicas para *views* e não devem existir em seu Domínio.

Sobre os virtuais, lembre-se que os dados que saem de seu `AppServices` devem já estar desconectados. O fato que vc vislumbrar que, de dentro da sua *view*, pode-se consumir propriedades virtuais afim de se aproveitar do recurso de *Lazy Load* do *Entity Framework* já indica uma má implementação. Pois estará criando um cenário onde, a partir de sua view, irá disparar um evento que irá fazer uma consulta em seu repositório. E isso é **muito** ruim. Os dados devem sair do seu `AppService` já prontos e desconectados.

Abaixo uma revisão na sua `Controller` que achei relevante:

```
public class DadosCandidatoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICandidatoAppService _candidatoApp;
    private readonly IDadosPessoaisAppService _dadosPessoasApp;
    // GET: Produtos

    public DadosCandidatoController(ICandidatoAppService candidatoApp, IDadosPessoaisAppService dadosPessoaisApp)
    {
        _candidatoApp = candidatoApp;
        _dadosPessoasApp = dadosPessoaisApp;
    }


    [HttpGet] // URL: /DadosCandidato/Candidato/123
    public ActionResult Candidato(int id)
    {
        var candidato = _candidatoApp.GetById(id);
        // Nas ultimas versoes do AutoMapper, 
        // não é mais necessário passa os tipos de origem e destino do mapeamento.
        // Basta por o destino, que o tipo de origim ele recupera pelo
        // objeto no parametro.
        var DadosCandidatoViewModel = Mapper.Map<DadosCandidatoViewModel>(candidato);

        // Por convenção, quando o nome da View é tem o mesmo nome da Action
        // não é necessário ser explícito, basta retornar os dados.
        return View(DadosCandidatoViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost] // URL: /DadosCandidato/Candidato/123
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Candidato([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]DadosCandidatoViewModel model)
    {    
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Mesma obs sobre AutoMapper
            var DadosPessoaisDomain = Mapper.Map<DadosPessoais>(model.DadosPessoaisViewModel);

            // Aqui voce deve apenar soliciar a inserção do dado
            // Checar se o dados já existe, e se exisitir atualizar é uma regra de negócio
            // Sendo regra de negócio, deve então ficar dentro de sua camada
            // de Domínio
            // A Controller deve ser a camada mais BURRA de sua aplicação
            // Ela apenas recebe dados e envia para o AppService
            // Ou recebe dados do AppService e transforma em ViewModels para exibição   
            _dadosPessoasApp.Add(DadosPessoaisDomain);
        }    

        return View("DadosCandidato", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gostaria de comentar o motivo das negativas?